# HTML Tiny image becomes blurry

Tags: html, image, pixel

I'm using this HTML

```
    <img src="stone.png" height="100" width="100"></img>
```

to display a tiny image that originally contains 5x5 pixels to instead be 100x100.  The image becomes extremely blurry when I do this.  Is there any way I ca retain the intentional "pixely" design when resizing it?

Note: I don't want to repeat the image, I just want to display it in a larger way and keep each pixel distinct.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

When you scale an image of 5x5 pixels to 100x100 there needs to be 20x interpolated pixels for each axis (generated synthetically using bi-cubic or bi-linear interpolation) between each points which will always result in a blurry image.

You cannot even fix a huge scale-up like that in dedicated software.

The only solution is to create your image at the intended resolution or close to it. It's also better to down-scale an image as you would remove information rather then generate it.